# How to style a form action

Tags: css

How would the following code be css, i am a beginner and cant seem
    to get my head around it

```
        <div id="page-container">
         <?php include_once("home_start.php"); ?> 
         <h1>Login</h1> 

        <form action='login process.php' method='POST'> 
         Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br /> 
         Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br /> 
         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'> 
         <input name='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'> 
        </form> 

         <h4><a href='register.php'>Register</a></h4> 

        <?php include_once("home_end.php"); ?> 

        </div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: you want to design a form???

Comment: I'm pretty sure your php files shouldn't spaces in them BTW

Comment: how would i style the code (form action above)

Comment: @user3158691 : what code mate???you have a form already....now do u want to make it look pretty??is that what you want???

Comment: @BetaBlaze `login process.php`

Comment: @user3158691 What do you want to style, the inputs, the form itself, the button? What do you want to style it to?

Comment: yep just to mack it look better, can't work out how to do this

Comment: the input , form and button

Comment: @user3158691, *make it look better* is very subjective. I might think making it lime green with a red background is better. Draw it out then change the CSS accordingly.

Comment: just so it looks more professional than the defalt

Comment: Look at the link at the bottom of my answer. There's a step-by-step example of the CSS used to make a decent looking form. You can use some of those ideas and change the CSS to customize to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class/ID to target this specific form (or any tag you have used if you want to target specific bits), then have the following HTML, for example:

```
<form id="red-form" action='login process.php' method='POST'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username'><br /> 
    Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br /> 
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'> 
    <input name='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'> 
</form>
```

Then use CSS to style that ID/class, e.g.:

```
#red-form {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Or you could just target all forms, then you don't need to add a class/ID and your CSS would be like:

```
form {
        background-color:red;
    }
```

Or just target the inputs:

```
input {
   background-color:blue; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C68FK/2/)

The world's your oyster really. See [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/style-web-forms-css/) for some ideas on how to style your form.

Comment: you don't need to add a class or an id you could simply use `form {background-color:red;}`

Comment: @Liam nah, that will be a general selector, to make it specific, you need to use an `id` or a `class`

Comment: @Mr.Alien : considering the present code....i think OP has only one form in mind...so i agree with LIAM :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien, didn't saying that was best practice, simply saying you could. The answer reads like this isn't possible

Answer (score 0):

You could target the individual input fields as follows:

```
input[type=text] { color:red; }
```